# Бинарные операторы в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дискретную математику немного понимаю, но суть побитовых операторов в Python уяснить пока не получается совсем

> Можно ли использовать побитовые операторы вместо логических:
>
> - `&` вместо `and`
> - `|` вместо `or`

Если нет, укажите, пожалуйста, предметную область в которой побитовые операторы станут незаменимы или очень уместны

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать битовые операции, если операндами являются булевы значения:

```
>>> True & False
False
>>> False & True
False
>>> False & False
False
>>> True & True
True
```

В таком случае всё верно, и ничего не нарушается. Однако в python пользователи часто используют булево представление объекта, не приводя его к булевому значению напрямую:

```
a = []
if a:
    print("Список не пуст")
```

В таком случае могут возникать исключения:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a & b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'
>>> a and b
[]
>>> a | b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'list'
>>> a or b
[1, 2, 3]
```

Хуже того - в отдельно взятых случаях, вероятно, такая замена может не вызывать исключений, а приводить к вычислительным ошибкам:

```
>>> 3 & 4
0
>>> 3 and 4
4
```

По этой причине настоятельно рекомендую не уходить от принятых булевых операторов, если нет желания работать исключительно с булевыми выражениями напрямую:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> bool(a) & bool(b)
False
>>> bool(a) and bool(b)
False
```

Для булевых операндов попарно равносильны операции `and`/`&` и `or`/`|`

Comment: Класс, спасибо!